# C# System.Web.HttpUnhandledExcpetion when changing page of table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a table in my web app that displays a list of users from my SQLExpress DB but for some reason when I navigate to page 8 I get this stacktrace in my logs:

> ERROR Global   Exception Logged in Global.asax.cs: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
>                      at BusinessLayer.Appl.UserDetailMgr.PopulateObjectFromReader(UserDetailMgr obj, IDataReader rdr)
>                      at BusinessLayer.Appl.UserDetailMgr..ctor(IDataReader dr)
>                      at BusinessLayer.Appl.UserDetailMgr.GetUserList(Int32 startIndex, Int32 recordsPerPage, Int32 colNo, Int32 order)
>                      at PresentationLayer.Pages.User.BSLeadListing.Display(String sortBycolumnNo)
>                      at PresentationLayer.Pages.User.BSLeadListing.gdPager_ItemCommand(Object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
>                      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnItemCommand(RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
>                      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnBubbleEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>                      at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>                      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
>                      at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>                      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>       2018-08-02 14:56:26,853 [6008] ERROR Global   Request URL: http://mednet.butterflyscheme.org.uk/WebEvaluation/Pages/User/BSLeadListing.aspx
>       2018-08-02 14:56:26,853 [6008] ERROR Global   Exception is not null & type of exception is 'HttpUnhandledException'.

Literally every page of the table works excpet page 8.
I have no clue where to start looking since I write the original code. Any thoughts would be much appreciated

When I look in my logs, it crashes just after this function is complete:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Repeater event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void gdPager_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Debug("gdPager_ItemCommand - Start");

        try
        {
            ViewState["UserListPageIndex"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            Display(Convert.ToString(ViewState["ColumnNo"]));

            PopulatePager();
        }
        finally
        {
            logger.Debug("gdPager_ItemCommand - End");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I searched for every value that would exist on page 8 using the search feature of the table while on the site. Every result displayed. So now I'm left wondering what is null?

Comment: can you show the code where you select the results from the database? Possibly there is some "invalid" data in a record on page 8. ... This means that tomorrow it could be page 9...

Comment: @Stefan Like I said I'm not too familiar with this code so I don't where the person gets the users into that table. I am so sorry for vagueness but I have nowhere else to turn

Comment: Maybe my updated answer helps?

Answer (score 0):

The error says

> Data is Null

It looks like the query returns no data, on page 8, and that causes the problem. you can use it in a try-catch.

I think you have not correctly calculated the number of pages, so page 7 should be the last page, however, still you have do add error handling there.

Comment: I searched for every value that would exist on page 8 using the search feature of the table while on the site. Every result displayed. So now I'm left wondering what is null?